# Duplicado de datos al hacer llamada API Angular

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Necesitaba imprimir datos de una API, eso ya se logró, pero ahora me duplica estos datos, como se ven en la imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es mi restaurants.component.html, aquí hago la llamada de los datos

```
                        <!-- SE REALIZA LA IMPRESIÓN DE LOS HORARIOS POR RESTAURANTE -->
                    <div class="restaurant-tabs" *ngFor="let apertura of restaurants">
                        <div class="tabs tabs-restaurant" >
                            <h2 class="lbl-rest-section text-center">
                                <strong>{{"RESTAURANT.restaurant_dias" | translate}}</strong>
                            </h2>
                            <div class="tabview-container" *ngIf="restaurant['aperturas'][0].length > 0; else noDays">
                                <a 
                                    *ngIf="enable_scroll_days" 
                                    href="javascript:void(0);" 
                                    class="tabview-scroll-btn tabview-scroll-btn-left" 
                                    (click)="scrollPrevious('tabview-custom-days')">
                                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
                                </a>
                                <p-tabView
                                    (onChange)="selectTab($event)"
                                    *ngFor="let info of restaurant['aperturas'] | keyvalue"
                                    styleClass="tabview-custom-days">
                                    <p-tabPanel *ngFor="let horario of info.value | keyvalue">
                                        <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                                            <span class="tab-header-item">{{horario.value.apertura}}</span>
                                            <span class="sub-header">
                                                {{horario.value.hora_inicio +' - '+ horario.value.hora_final}}
                                            </span>
                                        </ng-template>
                                        <div class="gallery-cat activiti-cat text-center">
                                          <ul class="list-inline">
                                              <li *ngFor="let days of horario.value.dias">
                                                    <span class="rest-day-lbl">
                                                      {{days}}
                                                    </span>
                                                </li>
                                          </ul>
                                      </div>
                                    </p-tabPanel>
                                </p-tabView>
                                <a 
                                    *ngIf="enable_scroll_days" 
                                    href="javascript:void(0);" 
                                    class="tabview-scroll-btn tabview-scroll-btn-right" 
                                    (click)="scrollNext('tabview-custom-days')">
                                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <ng-template #noDays>
                                <div class="avail-days-container" style="text-align: center;">
                                    <span> {{"RESTAURANT.restaurant_availabilityDays" | translate}} </span>
                                </div>
                            </ng-template>
                            <hr>                          
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

y esto es el restaurants.component.ts

```
getMenu(id:number){
this.idRestaurante = id;
for(var i=0; i<this.restaurants.length; i++){
  if(this.idRestaurante == this.restaurants[i].id){
    this.idRestaurante = this.restaurants[i];
  }
}
this._restaurantService.getPlatillos(this.lang,id).subscribe(
    response => {
      this.menu = this.groupBy(response, 'categoria');

      this._restaurantService.getPoliciesByRestaurant(this.lang, id).subscribe(
        response => {
          this.policies = response.politicas;
          this.loading = false;
          setTimeout(() => {      
            this.enable_scroll_days = this.verifyEnableCustomSideScroll("tabview-custom-days");
            this.enable_scroll_menu = this.verifyEnableCustomSideScroll("tabview-custom-menu");
          }, 100);              
        },
        error => {
          this.loading = false;
          this.error = true;
        }
      );
    },
    error => {
      this.loading = false;
      this.error = true;
    }
);

this.enable_scroll_days = this.verifyEnableCustomSideScroll("tabview-custom-days");
this.enable_scroll_menu = this.verifyEnableCustomSideScroll("tabview-custom-menu"); 




getRestaurants(lang){
this._restaurantService.getRestaurants(lang).subscribe(
     response => {
       let restaurants_info = this.mangeRestauranteInfo(response.restaurantes);
       this.restaurants = restaurants_info;
       this.loading = false;
     },
     error => {
       this.loading = false;
       this.error = true;
     }
   );
```

Todavía no puedo resolver el que se dupliquen los datos al momento de imprimirlos, Ya revise los datos que recibo de la llamada a la API y llegan sin duplicarse, el problema es al momento de imprimirlos en la web, los datos del restaurante llegan sin duplicarse, lo que se duplica son los días disponibles

Comment: hola creo que tu error esta  en que pones el `ngFor` en el  `p-tabView` y eso lo que hace es repetirte `n` veces el  `p-tabView` según la cantidad de resultados tengas en tu respuesta